# SourceSet with name 'jvmMain' not found

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to run kotlin multiplatform project with jvm and js source sets but am getting the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script '/private/var/folders/yc/sdfads/T/Home_main__.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'kotlin-multiplatform'.
> Could not create task ':Home.main()'.
   > SourceSet with name 'jvmMain' not found.
```

`Home` is the a class in `src/jvmMain/kotlin/Home.kt` and only has a `main()` function.

I tried to follow the docs as close as possible, there is not much of my own code. I just set the `jvmMain` source set to depend on `commonMain` and add a couple more libraries. My `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.3.72"
}

kotlin {
    jvm()
    js().browser()
//    android()

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common"))
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        jvm().compilations["main"].defaultSourceSet {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The project builds fine but when I run it, I get

> SourceSet with name 'jvmMain' not found.

Can anybody see what I'm missing, or is anyone hitting the same issue?

Comment: Do you have a folder named jvmMain with Kotlin source code in it in your project?

Comment: I have this same issue

Comment: looks like a KMP bug. still isn't fixed
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-13908/Its-impossible-to-run-main-method-from-Java-sources-of-a-multiplatform-project